# mysql unexpected END_OF_INPUT, expecting IF

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have a problem at the end of my procedure it says at the end of the KEYWORD "END" that the syntax is wrong, unexpected END_OF_INPUT, expecting IF - the very last line. I can't see what is wrong does anyone know what the problems is

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `leapfrog`.`new_procedure` ()
BEGIN
    IF new_parent_rgt < origin_lft THEN
        BEGIN
        END;
    ELSE IF (new_parent_rgt > origin_rgt) THEN
        BEGIN 
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        END;
    END IF;
END -- error here 'syntax error, unexpected END_OF_INPUT, expecting IF
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss the ; at end of `END IF`

And, you are using wrong the elseif:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `leapfrog`.`new_procedure` ()
BEGIN
    IF new_parent_rgt < origin_lft THEN
        BEGIN
        END;
    ELSEIF (new_parent_rgt > origin_rgt) THEN
        BEGIN 
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        END;
    END IF;
END
```

That should be OK :)

Comment: Can you update my code to show me what you're saying I don't get you're last comment

Comment: You're defining the delimiter '$$' at the start of your code, and you're not using it at the end of your trigger